# body driving forward or backward box2d

Tags: box2d, velocity, forward

I have a `b2_dynamicBody` which I move by `_body->ApplyForce` across the screen.

How do I find out, if it's moving forward or backwards?

I know how to find out the speed

```
b2Vec2 currentVelocity = _body->GetLinearVelocity();

float32 speed = currentVelocity.Normalize();
```

but not if its forward or backward.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the speed using `currentVelocity.Length()` which doesn't change the value.

If you define forward as left to right (increasing X), then your body is moving forward if currentVelocity.x > 0 and backwards if x < 0. If forward is up, then y > 0 is forward, y < 0 is backwards.

Comment: hhmmm... I have a ship which turns around from time to time and drives back from right to left. Then x<0 but still it's driving forward.... Isn't there a way to define what front and back is?

Comment: I have a Cocos2d Sprite connected to it with a png :-)

CCSprite *ship = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"ship.png"];
  ship.position = ccp(100, 39);
  [self addChild:ship];

Comment: Presumably you have a matrix or something that rotates the ship? If so, you can use that to find out which way your ship is facing.

Comment: So I have to track each time the ship turns around? I rotate the ship by SetTransform() Thanks for your help

Comment: If you have a transform for the current rotation you can run a vector of (1,0) through it to find out which way your ship is facing (assuming it is facing left when not rotated). Then all you need to do is check if the x value of the velocity has the same sign as the rotated facing vector.

Answer (score 0):

Velocity is a vector, made up from magnitude and direction. Normally direction on an axis is indicated by the sign of the value.

I would say you can say a body is moving backwards if the y portion of the *body relative* velocity is negative.